# problem changing gear volkswagen polo 2001

Tags: transmission

I have problem changing gear with my volkswagen polo 2001. I was told that a ball is missing

chendra Alwar

Comment: That's usually more of a problem with the driver than the car *ducks*. :-)

Comment: Is your vehicle a manual or automatic?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a manual transmission, it could very easily be one of the linkage balls is broke or missing. This is a very common malady with these cars.